# How to set datediff for a peewee column in python using sqlite as a database?

Tags: sqlite, peewee

I'm creating a project that has 3 fields, datestart, dateend and I need to generate the daypass field with the subtraction of the other two fields, I saw that it can be by query, but I couldn't use it

Comment: Please add to your question a) just *what* you saw b) what you tried and c) how you couldn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Postgres or MySQL, you should just subtract the fields:

```
query = MyModel.select(
    MyModel,  # All fields on MyModel.
    (MyModel.date_end - MyModel.date_start).alias('date_diff'))
```

If you're using Sqlite it all depends on how you've stored your datetimes. You can use the builtin sqlite date/time functions to convert to an int timestamp, for instance.

See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html for the list of sqlite date/time functions.

Comment: Does this query pass in my field?
The snippet of my code: